# 3gp to wav conversion using java

Tags: java, wav, 3gp

Is there a way by which, I can convert the 3gp files (recorded on mobile) to wav formatted files. I googled a bit and found ffmpeg could be used. I dont know how to use it with java. Anyone can suggest sample codes available for the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file3gp = new File("C:\\ffmpeg\\11.3gp");
        String fpstr = file3gp.getAbsolutePath();
        String outname = "C:\\ffmpeg\\wout.wav";
        String exeQuery = "ffmpeg -i "+fpstr+" -acodec pcm_u8 "+outname;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exeQuery);
    }
```

Comment: Install ffmpeg by following the steps shown in http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows